Easiest way to automatically find differences between a C enum and a Protocol Buffer enum for CI
My code defines an enum containing error codes. This enum is mirrored in a Protocol Buffer enum for serialized communication purpose. Here's an excerpt of each:
error.h:
typedef enum my_error {
    ERR_NONE = 0,
    ERR_NOT_INITIALIZED,
    ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY, 
    ERR_NULL_PTR, 
} my_error_t;

proto_error.proto:
enum StatusCode {
    ERR_NONE                                       = 0;
    ERR_NOT_INITIALIZED                            = 1;
    ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY                          = 2;
    ERR_NULL_PTR                                   = 3;
};

What would be a simple, maintainable (e.g., sed tends to be hard to decipher) way to alert me if a discrepancy occurs between the two? A discrepancy could be either differing order between elements or missing elements.
As you can see, a simple call to "diff" won't make it since the proto file contains explicit values for the elements and does not have exactly the same syntax as C. I couldn't find existing tools for this purpose. Would a simple parsing approach be easier to maintain than a full fledged program such as a Python script which instantiate copies of the enums to compare them?

Do they really need to use the very same identifiers? I would try to make both programs use the same header with same type definition. As an alternative you  might try to use different names. Then include both headers in one source file and use assertions like _Static_assert(ERR_NONE == PROTO_ERR_NONE, "enum mismatch!");

It would help if the code was syntactically valid…

@Gerhardh Sorry for the confusion, the second file in a protocol buffer (proto3) file, not a header.

@Ian Abbott I fixed the code to be syntactically correct.

Make a script to derive one from the other in the build time, rather than having them independent in two places. Or to derive both from a common source.

@EugeneSh. Hadn't thought about that. I think it actually makes more sense.

Doesn't the protobuf C library you are using have a generator utility that can handle enums?

Normally, a library such as nanopb or protobuf-c would be used to handle the parsing and generation of protobuf messages. Both nanopb and protobuf-c have generators that generate the code to to use a particular protobuf schema with the library. The generators may be run standalone, or may be invoked by the protoc compiler.  For example, nanopb has a standalone generator command nanopb_generator, and a generator that can be invoked by protoc --nanopb_out.
For example, the standalone generator can be used to process the proto_err.proto file and write the output proto_err.pb.c and proto_err.pb.h files to a directory called generated (which must already exist):
$ mkdir generated
$ nanopb_generator -D generated proto_err.proto

The same thing can be done using the nanopb generator invoked by protoc:
$ mkdir generated
$ protoc --nanopb_out generated proto_err.proto

Example of generated output from nanopb 0.4.8 follows…
Input: proto_err.proto :
enum StatusCode {
    ERR_NONE                                       = 0;
    ERR_NOT_INITIALIZED                            = 1;
    ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY                          = 2;
    ERR_NULL_PTR                                   = 3;
};

Output: generated/proto_err.pb.c :
/* Automatically generated nanopb constant definitions */
/* Generated by nanopb-0.4.8 */                                                 
                                                                                
#include "proto_err.pb.h"
#if PB_PROTO_HEADER_VERSION != 40
#error Regenerate this file with the current version of nanopb generator.
#endif

The generated .c file would normally have more stuff in it, but the input was too simple.
Output: generated/proto_err.pb.h :
/* Automatically generated nanopb header */
/* Generated by nanopb-0.4.8 */

#ifndef PB_PROTO_ERR_PB_H_INCLUDED
#define PB_PROTO_ERR_PB_H_INCLUDED
#include <pb.h>

#if PB_PROTO_HEADER_VERSION != 40
#error Regenerate this file with the current version of nanopb generator.
#endif

/* Enum definitions */
typedef enum _StatusCode {
    StatusCode_ERR_NONE = 0,
    StatusCode_ERR_NOT_INITIALIZED = 1,
    StatusCode_ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY = 2,
    StatusCode_ERR_NULL_PTR = 3
} StatusCode;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Helper constants for enums */
#define _StatusCode_MIN StatusCode_ERR_NONE
#define _StatusCode_MAX StatusCode_ERR_NULL_PTR
#define _StatusCode_ARRAYSIZE ((StatusCode)(StatusCode_ERR_NULL_PTR+1))


#ifdef __cplusplus
} /* extern "C" */
#endif

#endif

The generated output could be included and referred to by your other header files, for example:
myerror.h :
#include "generated/proto_err.pb.h"

typedef enum my_error {
    ERR_NONE = StatusCode_ERR_NONE,
    ERR_NOT_INITIALIZED = StatusCode_ERR_NOT_INITIALIZED,
    ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY = StatusCode_ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY, 
    ERR_NULL_PTR = StatusCode_ERR_NULL_PTR, 
} my_error_t;

That may be a bit error-prone to maintain, so it may be better not to do that, and to use the generated types and constants directly.

If you are not afraid of X macros, you can make a huge headache for your successor do many kinds of list processing.
For example, define a list as:
#define ENUM_VALUES(x) \
  x(ERR_NONE, 0) \
  x(ERR_NOT_INITIALIZED, 1) \
  x(ERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY, 2) \
  x(ERR_NULL_PTR, 3)

You can then generate the enum as:
 #define ENUM_GEN(n,v) n = v,
 typedef enum my_error {
   ENUM_VALUES(ENUM_GEN)
 } my_error_t;
 #undef ENUM_GEN

Then you can generate static asserts for equivalence with the header generated from a protobuf schema:
 #define ENUM_CHECK(n,v) static_assert(StatusCode_ ## n == n);
 ENUM_VALUES(ENUM_CHECK)
 #undef ENUM_CHECK

But this only makes sense if the list is really large. Normally it would be preferrable to simply write out the tests - its a bit more work to update, but a lot less things to understand. In any case, please use explicit values also on C side so that they are easier to check.
